# C language / How to read input from one file and write an output to another file

Tags: c

I am having a problem with  reading input from one file and write an output to another file.

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//Variables declarations
FILE *reportfile;
FILE *inputfile;
char ratioName[20];
char nameorganization[25];
int asset1,asset2,asset3;
int lia1,lia2,lia3;
float asset;
float liabilites;
float ratio;
int ave_asset;
int ave_liabilites;
float ave_ratio;
char year[5]
//char currentasset[15];
//char currentLia[30];
//char tekstRatio[45];


//void
void ReadingData(void);
void DoCalcs(void);
void Report(void);


int main(void) {
    ReadingData();
    DoCalcs();
    Report();


 return 0;
}

void ReadingData(void){
    inputfile = fopen("c:\\class\\current.txt" , "r");
    fgets(nameorganization,25, inputfile);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d%d\n", &asset1, &lia1);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d%d\n", &asset2, &lia2);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%d%d", &asset3, &lia3);
   fclose(inputfile);
}

void DoCalcs(void){
    ratio = asset / liabilites;
    ave_asset = (asset1 + asset2 + asset3) / 3;
    ave_liabilites = (lia1 + lia2 + lia3) / 3;
    ave_ratio = ratio / 3;
}

void Report(void){
    reportfile = fopen("c:\\class\\alimbetm_cr.txt","w");
    fprintf(reportfile,"\n");
    fprintf(reportfile,"Current Ratio Report",ratioName);
    fprintf(reportfile,"Year");
    //fprintf(reportfile,"Current Asset",currentasset);


}


//void GettingInfo(void){
    //printf("Please type ratio: ");
    //scanf();
//}
```

when I run it , it saves file to new disk but removes old data, that is NOT what I want. 
What I want is read input/data from one file and write bot input/output to another file without removing input.

This is input file data (current.txt)

```
Hi-Tech Leisure Products
47900       31007
34500        9100
57984       14822
```

This how it should be on a new file

```
Hi-Tech Leisure Products
Current Ratio Report

                Current           Current          Current
Year            Assets            Liabilities      Ratio
----------------------------------------------------------
2010              47900             31007             1.54
2011              34500              9100             3.79
2012              57984             14822             3.91
----------------------------------------------------------
Average           46795             18310             3.08

This report produced by Raul Jimenez.
```

please help

Comment: Are you saying that `current.txt` gets deleted?

Comment: Why are all your variables *global* and all your function parameter lists *void*?

Comment: Not related to your question: But you should close the output file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want the *old contents* of the output file to be overwritten by the *new report*, right? Then you need to open the output file in append mode. If this is not what you're asking, please clarify your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @kaylum yes current.txt gets deleated

Comment: I edited my question, please guys take a look

Comment: @thebusybee I edited my question, please take a look

Comment: Alright, you need to get back to your C book and learn about using the `printf()`-family and its format specifier.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would delete `current.txt`. You may be misinterpreting the results or something else, not your program, is deleting `current.txt`.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are  numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5, 20, 25.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT:  it is a poor programming practice to make all the variables 'global' rather than encapsulate them as local variables in functions and passing them as parameters to called functions.

Comment: OT: regarding: `inputfile = fopen("c:\\class\\current.txt" , "r");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL)` the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen failed" );` which passes the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: OT: when calling `fgets()` and/or `fscanf()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  for `fgets()` the returned value must not be NULL.  for `fscanf() the returned value must match the number of `input format conversion` specifiers.  Note: when compiling always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding: `fgets(nameorganization,25, inputfile);` and `Hi-Tech Leisure Products`  The variable: `nameorganization[]` is only 25 characters long so does not have room for the '\n' at the end of the line in the input file.  so that '\n' will be the first character seen by the first call to `fscanf()`  (which, fortunately, has a `%d` format specifier, which will consume that leading 'white space'.   Much better to use `sizeof( nameorganization )` rather than the literal 25, as that will allow easy changes to the size of the `nameorganization[]` array without having to fix multiple places

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need to use `"a"` instead of `"w"` because `write` function is used to clear the old data and write the new one

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does not compile! The first problem is this statement:

```
char year[5]
```

which is missing the trailing semicolon `;`.

regarding:

```
#include <math.h>
```

None of the 'features' of `math.h` are being used in the posted code.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing that statement.

regarding:

```
reportfile = fopen("c:\\class\\alimbetm_cr.txt","w");
```

The mode `w` causes the output file to be truncated to 0 length.

Since you want to keep the old contents of the output file and simply add more data. Strongly suggest using;

```
reportfile = fopen("c:\\class\\alimbetm_cr.txt","a");
```

where the mode `a` will open the output file in `append` mode so the new data is added to the end of the existing file.

Of course, always check `reportfile` to assure it is not NULL (I.E. the call to `fopen()` was successful.

Note this statement does not compile:

```
fprintf(reportfile,"Current Ratio Report",ratioName);
```

because it has a parameter but no matching 'output format conversion' specifier. Suggest (in this case) dropping the parameter: `ratioName`

the calls to `fopen()` and `fclose()` are scattered all over the code.   As it is currently written, only one record will be read from the input file and only one record will be written to the output file.  This will be a major problem when the input file contains multiple records.

the 'desired output'  indicates that the first thing should be: "Hi-Tech Leisure Products"  then: "Current Ratio Report" however, there is no statement (in `Report()`) to actually output that second statement  AND the char array `ratioName[]` is never set to any specific value.

the 'desired output' indicates 2 lines of column headers, etc but there is no code to actually output those column headers ( other than `year` ).  Similar considerations exist for the data lines, the `Average:` line, the `author` line.  Each datum of each line needs to be specifically output by the code, they will not 'magically' appear in the output file.

regarding;

```
ratio = asset / liabilites;
```

Neither `asset` nor `liabilites` is ever set to any specific value so they will be (due to where they are declared) containing the value(s) 0.0f.  So this division will result in a DIVIDE BY ZERO crash of the code.

There are plenty more problems, but the above should get you started in the right direction.